# How to read previous app.config value when we updating an installer

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield

We are working on a WPF application and we have used Install Shield  Limited edition to create the installer of the application.

As per requirement  we need to keep a “Key”  and  “Value” in the app-settings of the “app.config” file.  “Value” will be dynamically generated at the time of installation and it will be different  when we update to new version(installing the new versions of the application).

I found that each installation time app.config file is overwriting.  How i get the old config “value” when we installing new setup.

Can i get the old value from an installer class?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is in the installer you wrote, not in the WPF application.  I've never used any version of Install Shield, but it seems to me that your installer needs to check if there is an existing install, and if so, read the "name" and "value" values from the existing app.config, then write whatever you need to the new app.config after the install is completed.  I have no idea how you'd implement that, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in custom actions, it is like PreBuild/PostBuild actions in Visual Studio. If you are not comfortable with scripts (neither am I), you could write two executables in C#, one to be executed before overwriting the old files to get the old values, the other to be executed after installation to restore the old values.

Comment: Advanced Installer (disclaimer: I work on its development) has built-in functionality for this, so you don't need to write any code. This functionality it is not in the free edition, but now it all depends on what value you place on your time http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-XML-locator.html